# How can I take free space from /home to create a new storage partition?

Tags: linux

My current partitioning is like this:

```
lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0     4G  0 loop  /var/tmp
nvme0n1     259:0    0   3.5T  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   256M  0 part
│ └─md0       9:0    0   256M  0 raid1 /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0     8G  0 part
│ └─md1       9:1    0     8G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0     2G  0 part
│ └─md2       9:2    0     2G  0 raid1 /boot
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   300G  0 part
│ └─md3       9:3    0 299.9G  0 raid1 /
└─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0   3.2T  0 part
  └─md4       9:4    0   3.2T  0 raid1 /home
nvme1n1     259:6    0   3.5T  0 disk
├─nvme1n1p1 259:7    0   256M  0 part
│ └─md0       9:0    0   256M  0 raid1 /boot/efi
├─nvme1n1p2 259:8    0     8G  0 part
│ └─md1       9:1    0     8G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─nvme1n1p3 259:9    0     2G  0 part
│ └─md2       9:2    0     2G  0 raid1 /boot
├─nvme1n1p4 259:10   0   300G  0 part
│ └─md3       9:3    0 299.9G  0 raid1 /
└─nvme1n1p5 259:11   0   3.2T  0 part
  └─md4       9:4    0   3.2T  0 raid1 /home
```

I would like to create a separate partition with 1.5 TB Storage and need to take the free space from `/home`. How can i configure it with or without raid?

Answer (score 1):

To shrink a partition, you must ensure it's first unmounted; the best way is to boot to a live CD/USB. I recommend GParted as this environment will have all the tools you need to complete the task. https://gparted.org/livecd.php

Once the Live CD has booted, launch GParted from the system menu, right-click the partition, you want to resize, and select "Resize/Move."

Once you have set the new size information, click apply and boot back into your normal environment. The home partition will now be a new size, and your disk will have unallocated space you can use for a new partition.

There is also a guide on their website that you can follow https://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dmoving-space-between-partitions. You only need to follow step 6 for what you need.